# Find files in given subdirectories from Unix command line

Tags: bash, find

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
a/
a/b1
a/b1/src
a/b1/target
a/b2
a/b2/src
a/b2/target
```

I need to find all files by name pattern `abc*` only in subdirectories `src`, i.e. in `a/b1/src` and `a/b2/src`. How can I do it with `find` command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `-name and -path` options:

```
find . -name "*abc*" -path "*src*"
```

This will search file names with pattern `*abc*` in the path matching `*src*` only.